# Extract from a Dropbox account with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, download

I am attempting to pull data from a Dropbox account with Excel VBA.

I removed the URL to make the generic script easier to follow:

```
Sub DownloadFile()

Dim myURL As String
myURL = "Some URL HEre"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
WinHttpReq.send

myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "C:\Users\Eric\Downloads\Miami.txt", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
    oStream.Close
End If

End Sub
```

My original URL is the Dropbox URL, which includes the text file in the sub directories (..../..../somefile.txt). I do not know what to do for the username and password options, and left those untouched when I originally ran the file.

When I did run the code, I had success, however I had a mass amount of HTML code pulled and not the text file downloaded.

Comment: Dropbox has a .NET API, so I suggest you try C# or VB.net. Either create a dll or standalone program that you can call from VBA, or create your entire solution in interop.